# Which of the two should I choose when I meant one particular situation, understanding the subject is plural

Tags: grammar

(1) [ Members of an organization / Members of the organization ] may arbitrarily interpret what is not mentioned in the code of conduct, namely the silence, so long as they do not violate the written code of conduct especially when they have (2) [a particular situation / particular situations ] to which there is no item or rule to apply.  In other words, they may make the unethical decision that they take an action when it is not evaluated and rather unethical, which is called "Loophole Ethics".  (I wrote it myself)

(1) Which of the two should I choose when I meant them in general?
(2) Which of the two should I choose when I meant one particular situation, understanding the subject is plural.

Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: In the first sentence your question appears to be about the difference between **the** organization and **an** organization.  In the second sentence your question appears to be about **a situation** versus **situations**.   Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: this depends on the context - for example whether you’re talking to people who are in the organisation already or prospective members. It could also change depending on how many organisations the rules are for.
If the rules are for people who are already in the organisation or it’s just for one organisation, you’d use “members of the organisation”. 
If they’re not already members or it’s for multiple organisations, it would be “members of an organisation”.
As a native speaker, I’d tend to stick with “members of the organisation”.

Part 2: “when they have a particular situation” sounds much better to me in the context. I understand what the other option is implying, but it sounds like it was written by a non-native speaker.
There’s no need to imply plural(particular situations) because of the structure of the previous sentences.
The previous sentences dictate that it will be on a case by case basis so there’s no need for plural. It’s hard to explain so hopefully you understand what I mean.